# Как технически реализовано всплывающее окно в lightbox?

Tags: javascript, lightbox

То есть

1. затемнение (предполагаю, что к body присваивается background-color = black и opacity = 0.5, например)
2. появившаяся картинка не затемнена, а лежит как будто бы в слое поверх body.

Пример: http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/

Спасибо.

Comment: + это реализовано наверно с помощью position:)

Answer (score 2):

Не правильно думаете.

Создается какой-нибудь div элемент со свойствами (будет служить затемняющей подложкой):

```
position: fixed; width:100%; height: 100%; top:0; left:0; background: rgba(0,0,0,.5); z-index:10;
```

На этот div вешается обработчик, который закрывает просмотр.

Создается второй элемент, который будет служить контейнером для картинок. В css стилях выставляется типа:

```
position: absolute; left: 50%; z-index:20;
```

И в javascript (jQuery):

```
$('img').click(function() {
    $('.lightbox').css({
        'width':this.width, 
        'margin-left':'-'+(this.width/2), 
        'height': this.height
    }).find('img').attr('href', this.src);
});
```

Примерно вот так.